# Implementing Option#map2

Tags: scala

Working on an example from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I'm working on `Option#map2`:

```
override def map2[A, B, C](fa: Option[A],fb: Option[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Option[C] = {
  (fa, fb) match {
    case (None, _) => None
    case (_, None) => None
    case (_, _) => Some(f(fa.get, fb.get)) // runtime-safe get calls
  }
}
```

Is the above implementation reasonable? I presumed that, if either `fa` or `fb` were `None`, then so should be the returned value. Pattern matching seemed the most clean to me, but perhaps there's a cleaner or more concise way to write this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct - it should work nicely.

The first thing that I would improve on is the `// runtime-safe get calls`. This is an anti-pattern in Scala and is generally discouraged. In this case you can use pattern matchings powerful extractors to get the value the `Option` is storing:

```
case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(f(a, b))
```

But instead of pattern matching the most elegant way to solve this problem is to use [for comprehensions](http://daily-scala.blogspot.fr/2009/08/for-comprehensions.html). It is functionally the same as your code:

```
override def map2[A, B, C](fa: Option[A], fb: Option[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Option[C] = {
  for {
    a <- fa
    b <- fb
  } yield f(a, b)
}
```

Since `Option` is essentially a collection with either zero or one element it can be used in for-comprehensions. The variable `a` will only be populated if `fa` is a `Some`. If either is `None` then nothing will be yielded and the result is `None`.

Comment: Thanks, Akos. Could you please provide a reference for `.get` being an anti-pattern? It makes sense to me, but I'd appreciate a reference for further reading

Comment: Sorry, I may have overused the word "anti-pattern" as it is not explicitly stated anywhere. The issue is that `.get` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the `Option` is empty. In this case you *know* that it won't be empty, but what happens when you or someone refactors it? Will they make sure that the `.get` will be called on a code path that is safe? It is generally encouraged (not only in Scala) to avoid this, because you're just setting yourself up for bugs. I would recommend a talk on this topic, it covers the issue and Scala's solution to it quite well: http://youtu.be/gVXt1RG_yN0

Comment: Thanks! I went to NeScala 2014 and was thinking of that video right as I clicked your link!

Comment: When I use it like this `Option.map2(Some(3), None)(_+_)` it fails why?

Comment: @eguneys The issue is that `None` is essentially `Option[Nothing]` and the `_ + _` then translates to `Int + Nothing`. This can't compile as `Nothing` can't be added with `Int`, to fix this use `Option.empty[Int]` instead of `None`!